# How to draw a chess board in D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, chess

I would like to draw a chess board in D3:

[image: Initial game position]

I would be satisfied with just being able to draw the initial game position (as above).

It may be the case that one does not need image files for king, queen, knight, etc. (there are 12 distinct pieces) since they are all part of [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode) as codepoints 2654-265F:

[image: Unicode chess symbols]

The Unicode characters appear in any modern browser:

♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙

♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟

Unicode chess symbols on Wikipedia: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode)

Python script to display chess board in a terminal using Unicode characters: [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/423640/unicode-chessboard-in-a-terminal). Its result:

[image]

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the code used by https://github.com/JakeBecker/D3-Chess or http://htmlchess.sourceforge.net/demo/example.html or http://www.vectomatic.org/games/lib-gwt-svg-chess

Comment: @JasonAller, no, I never visited these pages, great links! I'll take a look.

Comment: It took some remembering to come up with http://chessboardjs.com/examples#1000 Your question is pretty close to several  of the following: "really good way" makes it seems like an opinion question, it lends itself to answers that suggest libraries and questions aren't supposed to do that, the line about initial position sets the stage for follow up questions without providing the additional specifications that will accompany them.

Comment: @JasonAller, for all you said I am sure I can convince you in fair and free discussion that you are totally wrong, but I don't have energy to waste on rectifying your distorted opinions.

Comment: I didn't vote it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/VividD/pen/bNgGKP) of the solution.

[image]

### CODE WALKTROUGH

Definition of enumerated type for all chess pieces:

```
var pieces = {
    NONE :          {name: "None",          code: " "}, 
    WHITE_KING :    {name: "White King",    code: "\u2654"}, 
    WHITE_QUEEN :   {name: "White Queen",   code: "\u2655"}, 
    WHITE_ROOK :    {name: "White Rook",    code: "\u2656"}, 
    WHITE_BISHOP :  {name: "White Bishop",  code: "\u2657"}, 
    WHITE_KNIGHT :  {name: "White Knight",  code: "\u2658"}, 
    WHITE_POWN :    {name: "White Pown",    code: "\u2659"}, 
    BLACK_KING :    {name: "Black King",    code: "\u265A"}, 
    BLACK_QUEEN :   {name: "Black Queen",   code: "\u265B"}, 
    BLACK_ROOK :    {name: "Black Rook",    code: "\u265C"}, 
    BLACK_BISHOP :  {name: "Black Bishop",  code: "\u265D"}, 
    BLACK_KNIGHT :  {name: "Black Knight",  code: "\u265E"}, 
    BLACK_POWN :    {name: "Black Pown",    code: "\u265F"}, 
};
```

Board initialization:

```
    var board =[];

    for(var i = 0; i < boardDimension*boardDimension; i++) {
        board.push({
            x: i % boardDimension,
            y: Math.floor(i / boardDimension),
            piece: pieces.NONE
        });
    };

    board[0].piece = pieces.BLACK_ROOK
    board[1].piece = pieces.BLACK_KNIGHT
    board[2].piece = pieces.BLACK_BISHOP
    board[3].piece = pieces.BLACK_QUEEN
    board[4].piece = pieces.BLACK_KING
    board[5].piece = pieces.BLACK_BISHOP
    board[6].piece = pieces.BLACK_KNIGHT
    board[7].piece = pieces.BLACK_ROOK

    board[8].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[9].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[10].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[11].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[12].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[13].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[14].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[15].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN

    board[6*8 + 0].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 1].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 2].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 3].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 4].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 5].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 6].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 7].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN

    board[7*8 + 0].piece = pieces.WHITE_ROOK
    board[7*8 + 1].piece = pieces.WHITE_KNIGHT
    board[7*8 + 2].piece = pieces.WHITE_BISHOP
    board[7*8 + 3].piece = pieces.WHITE_QUEEN
    board[7*8 + 4].piece = pieces.WHITE_KING
    board[7*8 + 5].piece = pieces.WHITE_BISHOP
    board[7*8 + 6].piece = pieces.WHITE_KNIGHT
    board[7*8 + 7].piece = pieces.WHITE_ROOK
```

Drawing squares:

```
    svg.append("rect")
         .style("class", "fields")
         .style("class", "rects")
         .attr("x", function (d) {
             return d.x*fieldSize;
         })
         .attr("y", function (d) {
             return d.y*fieldSize;
         })
         .attr("width", fieldSize + "px")
         .attr("height", fieldSize + "px")
         .style("fill", function (d) {
             if ( ((d.x%2 == 0) && (d.y%2 == 0)) ||
                  ((d.x%2 == 1) && (d.y%2 == 1))    ) 
                 return "beige";
             else
                 return "tan";
         });
```

Drawing pieces, using Unicode characters:

```
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x*fieldSize;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y*fieldSize;
        })
        .style("font-size", "40")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", "35px")
        .attr("dx", "20px")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.piece.code;
         })
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.piece.name;
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for public knowledge I made a mini plugin for plot a chessboard via d3.

You can see it in https://github.com/jbkunst/d3-chessboard.

How it works:

```
    var sel = d3.select("#chess-container");
    var board = d3chessboard();
    sel.call(board);
```

[image]