# Is this a correct way of implementing an enumeration?

Tags: javascript, enums

I am writing the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806132/how-to-draw-a-chess-board-in-d3).

I am not sure if my implementation of enumeration is OK. I'll describe it in a moment. Please review it, and tell me if I could have done something better.

The small prototype in question ([codepen](http://codepen.io/VividD/pen/bNgGKP) here) involves drawing chess board and chess pieces. There are 6 white and 6 black chess pieces. For each of them, I need to keep its name (like `"White Bishop"`) and Unicode code (something like `"\u2654"`). So, I defined variable `pieces` as follows: (There is also piece `NONE` that proved to be useful for empty squares on the board)

```
var pieces = {
    NONE :          {name: "None",          code: " "}, 
    WHITE_KING :    {name: "White King",    code: "\u2654"}, 
    WHITE_QUEEN :   {name: "White Queen",   code: "\u2655"}, 
    WHITE_ROOK :    {name: "White Rook",    code: "\u2656"}, 
    WHITE_BISHOP :  {name: "White Bishop",  code: "\u2657"}, 
    WHITE_KNIGHT :  {name: "White Knight",  code: "\u2658"}, 
    WHITE_POWN :    {name: "White Pown",    code: "\u2659"}, 
    BLACK_KING :    {name: "Black King",    code: "\u265A"}, 
    BLACK_QUEEN :   {name: "Black Queen",   code: "\u265B"}, 
    BLACK_ROOK :    {name: "Black Rook",    code: "\u265C"}, 
    BLACK_BISHOP :  {name: "Black Bishop",  code: "\u265D"}, 
    BLACK_KNIGHT :  {name: "Black Knight",  code: "\u265E"}, 
    BLACK_POWN :    {name: "Black Pown",    code: "\u265F"}, 
};
```

I keep data on the distribution of all pieces on the board in an array called board, a this is the initialization of that array:

```
   var board =[];

    for(var i = 0; i < boardDimension*boardDimension; i++) {
        board.push({
            x: i % boardDimension,
            y: Math.floor(i / boardDimension),
            piece: pieces.NONE
        });
    };

    board[0].piece = pieces.BLACK_ROOK
    board[1].piece = pieces.BLACK_KNIGHT
    board[2].piece = pieces.BLACK_BISHOP
    board[3].piece = pieces.BLACK_QUEEN
    board[4].piece = pieces.BLACK_KING
    board[5].piece = pieces.BLACK_BISHOP
    board[6].piece = pieces.BLACK_KNIGHT
    board[7].piece = pieces.BLACK_ROOK

    board[8].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[9].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[10].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[11].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[12].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[13].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[14].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[15].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN

    board[6*8 + 0].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 1].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 2].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 3].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 4].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 5].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 6].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6*8 + 7].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN

    board[7*8 + 0].piece = pieces.WHITE_ROOK
    board[7*8 + 1].piece = pieces.WHITE_KNIGHT
    board[7*8 + 2].piece = pieces.WHITE_BISHOP
    board[7*8 + 3].piece = pieces.WHITE_QUEEN
    board[7*8 + 4].piece = pieces.WHITE_KING
    board[7*8 + 5].piece = pieces.WHITE_BISHOP
    board[7*8 + 6].piece = pieces.WHITE_KNIGHT
    board[7*8 + 7].piece = pieces.WHITE_ROOK
```

And, deep down in the code, this data is used in the following way:

```
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x*fieldSize;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y*fieldSize;
    })
    .style("font-size", "40")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", "35px")
    .attr("dx", "20px")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.piece.code;
     })
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.piece.name;
    });
```

Did I define and use the enumeration in the right way?

Comment: what you've used is an object and there is nothing called enum in javascript and if you've achieved your work as you want to, then it must be correct.

Comment: @AmitJoki All right, but I meant enumeration in conceptual sense. Maybe I should cleanse myself of that concept altogether, while programming in JavaScript?

Comment: a rose by any other name; it does what you want. In  "real" enums, you traditionally (hence eNUMeration) get a number value and you usually don't have to specify the numbers: they auto-increment under basic syntax. but again, the interaction between enums and what you have is very comparable. also, don't forget that you can say a=b=c=1 to cut down repitition when assigning common values to many locations.

Comment: Well actually this code is doing the trick here but it only have to be constant, and never changes to be an Enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start there's no *Enum* in Javascript, but you can implement it by your own, and looking at the work you have done, I think that's correct and it's a good try.

But if we focus on the logic of **Enum**, we should know that an **Enum** must be **constant** and its **elements values should never change** so we have to look for a more suitable solution because in **Javascript** we can **overwrite** any **object**.

After a search I've made, I found a Javascript method that can provide the solution, wich is the **[Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)**.

So after *defining* your Enum you should *freeze* it, so it'll never change:

```
var pieces = {
 NONE :          {name: "None",          code: " "}, 
 WHITE_KING :    {name: "White King",    code: "\u2654"}, 
 WHITE_QUEEN :   {name: "White Queen",   code: "\u2655"}, 
 WHITE_ROOK :    {name: "White Rook",    code: "\u2656"}, 
 WHITE_BISHOP :  {name: "White Bishop",  code: "\u2657"}, 
 WHITE_KNIGHT :  {name: "White Knight",  code: "\u2658"}, 
 WHITE_POWN :    {name: "White Pown",    code: "\u2659"}, 
 BLACK_KING :    {name: "Black King",    code: "\u265A"}, 
 BLACK_QUEEN :   {name: "Black Queen",   code: "\u265B"}, 
 BLACK_ROOK :    {name: "Black Rook",    code: "\u265C"}, 
 BLACK_BISHOP :  {name: "Black Bishop",  code: "\u265D"}, 
 BLACK_KNIGHT :  {name: "Black Knight",  code: "\u265E"}, 
 BLACK_POWN :    {name: "Black Pown",    code: "\u265F"}, 
};
var frozenpieces=Object.freeze(pieces);
```

In that case the `frozenpieces` Object will remain always the same, so we can assume that it's an Enum.

Comment: I believe this is an excellent observation. It would make the code more robust at least.