# Chess moves in D3

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg, chess

Drawing a chess board with D3 is discussed in this question:

[How to draw a chess board in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806132/how-to-draw-a-chess-board-in-d3)

[image]

Also, there is an incredible D3 chess board plugin by @jbkunst:

[d3-chessboard plugin](https://github.com/jbkunst/d3-chessboard)

[image]

However, I would like to animate chess moves, like this:

[image]

(but a lot smoother; with configurable duration etc.)

Do you have any advice how to do it, D3 style?

I would be happy with animation of just one move for now. I will build up the more general solution later.

Comment: I know that the question required d3, but there are a lot of chess plugins out there, complete with functionality, that might do better. That being said, I am trying to understand how you are moving the pieces. Are you using the chess plugin or are you drawing it all yourself as in the first link?

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex I would prefer having stand-alone solution to the one that relies on the plugin, but both could be interesting to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation using chained transitions to make the pieces step across the board.  I've tried to account for two different types of movement, "line" where the pieces move in a straight line (ie bishop, castle) and "step" where they move step-wise (ie knight).  I based it off your work in the previous question.

```
// piece is the text element to move
// position is an object like { x: 4, y: 6 } of the board position to move to
// type is "step" or "line"
function movePiece(piece, position, type) {

  var p = d3.select(piece),
      d = p.datum();

  (function repeat() {

    if (type === "step"){
      if (position.y === d.y) {
        if (position.x === d.x) {
          return;
        } else if (position.x > d.x) {
          d.x += 1;
        } else {
          d.x -= 1;
        }
      } else {
        if (position.y > d.y) {
          d.y += 1;
        } else {
          d.y -= 1;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (position.x === d.x &&
          position.y === d.y) {
          return;
      }
      else {
        if (position.x != d.x){
          if (position.x > d.x) {
            d.x += 1;
          } else {
            d.x -= 1;
          }
        }
        if (position.y != d.y){
          if (position.y > d.y) {
            d.y += 1;
          } else {
            d.y -= 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    p = p.transition()
      .transition()
      .attr("x", d.x * fieldSize)
      .attr("y", d.y * fieldSize)
      .each("end", repeat);
  })();
}
```

*Note*, I didn't attempt to code whether it's a legal move.

---

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var pieces = {
      NONE: {
        name: "None",
        code: " "
      },
      WHITE_KING: {
        name: "White King",
        code: "\u2654"
      },
      WHITE_QUEEN: {
        name: "White Queen",
        code: "\u2655"
      },
      WHITE_ROOK: {
        name: "White Rook",
        code: "\u2656"
      },
      WHITE_BISHOP: {
        name: "White Bishop",
        code: "\u2657"
      },
      WHITE_KNIGHT: {
        name: "White Knight",
        code: "\u2658"
      },
      WHITE_POWN: {
        name: "White Pown",
        code: "\u2659"
      },
      BLACK_KING: {
        name: "Black King",
        code: "\u265A"
      },
      BLACK_QUEEN: {
        name: "Black Queen",
        code: "\u265B"
      },
      BLACK_ROOK: {
        name: "Black Rook",
        code: "\u265C"
      },
      BLACK_BISHOP: {
        name: "Black Bishop",
        code: "\u265D"
      },
      BLACK_KNIGHT: {
        name: "Black Knight",
        code: "\u265E"
      },
      BLACK_POWN: {
        name: "Black Pown",
        code: "\u265F"
      },
    };

    var board = [],
      boardDimension = 8,
      fieldSize = 40;

    for (var i = 0; i < boardDimension * boardDimension; i++) {
      board.push({
        x: i % boardDimension,
        y: Math.floor(i / boardDimension),
        piece: pieces.NONE
      });
    };

    board[0].piece = pieces.BLACK_ROOK
    board[1].piece = pieces.BLACK_KNIGHT
    board[2].piece = pieces.BLACK_BISHOP
    board[3].piece = pieces.BLACK_QUEEN
    board[4].piece = pieces.BLACK_KING
    board[5].piece = pieces.BLACK_BISHOP
    board[6].piece = pieces.BLACK_KNIGHT
    board[7].piece = pieces.BLACK_ROOK

    board[8].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[9].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[10].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[11].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[12].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[13].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[14].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN
    board[15].piece = pieces.BLACK_POWN

    board[6 * 8 + 0].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6 * 8 + 1].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6 * 8 + 2].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6 * 8 + 3].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6 * 8 + 4].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6 * 8 + 5].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6 * 8 + 6].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN
    board[6 * 8 + 7].piece = pieces.WHITE_POWN

    board[7 * 8 + 0].piece = pieces.WHITE_ROOK
    board[7 * 8 + 1].piece = pieces.WHITE_KNIGHT
    board[7 * 8 + 2].piece = pieces.WHITE_BISHOP
    board[7 * 8 + 3].piece = pieces.WHITE_QUEEN
    board[7 * 8 + 4].piece = pieces.WHITE_KING
    board[7 * 8 + 5].piece = pieces.WHITE_BISHOP
    board[7 * 8 + 6].piece = pieces.WHITE_KNIGHT
    board[7 * 8 + 7].piece = pieces.WHITE_ROOK

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(board)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .style("class", "fields")
      .style("class", "rects")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x * fieldSize;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y * fieldSize;
      })
      .attr("width", fieldSize + "px")
      .attr("height", fieldSize + "px")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (((d.x % 2 == 0) && (d.y % 2 == 0)) ||
          ((d.x % 2 == 1) && (d.y % 2 == 1)))
          return "beige";
        else
          return "tan";
      });

    var pieces = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(board)
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        d.piece.x = d.x;
        return d.x * fieldSize;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        d.piece.y = d.y;
        return d.y * fieldSize;
      })
      .style("font-size", "40")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", "35px")
      .attr("dx", "20px")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.piece.code;
      })

    pieces
      .append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.piece.name;
      });

    movePiece(pieces[0][6], {
      x: 5,
      y: 2
    }, "step");
    
    movePiece(pieces[0][58], {
      x: 5,
      y: 4
    }, "line");
    
    function movePiece(piece, position, type) {
      
      var p = d3.select(piece),
          d = p.datum();
          
      (function repeat() {

        if (type === "step"){
          if (position.y === d.y) {
            if (position.x === d.x) {
              return;
            } else if (position.x > d.x) {
              d.x += 1;
            } else {
              d.x -= 1;
            }
          } else {
            if (position.y > d.y) {
              d.y += 1;
            } else {
              d.y -= 1;
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (position.x === d.x &&
              position.y === d.y) {
              return;
          }
          else {
            if (position.x != d.x){
              if (position.x > d.x) {
                d.x += 1;
              } else {
                d.x -= 1;
              }
            }
            if (position.y != d.y){
              if (position.y > d.y) {
                d.y += 1;
              } else {
                d.y -= 1;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        p = p.transition()
          .transition()
          .attr("x", d.x * fieldSize)
          .attr("y", d.y * fieldSize)
          .each("end", repeat);
      })();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the start position and the stop position, you can set a transition() for whatever process is moving the pieces. That will make it tween between the states in an animated fashion. This will be linear, though, so it will look nice for anyone who moves along the grid in a straight line, less good if you don't (e.g. a knight). For a knight, I would first transition along one axis, and then along the other.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some research, I found this: http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/ which pretty much gives the same answer as nucleon: when you want to change attributes of an element (like position) in d3 and you do something like d3.select(selector).attr(attribute,value) and you have to use d3.select(selector).transition().attr(attribute,value)

However, the way the chessboard is drawn by the plugin, for example, you have g elements that represent squares, containing a rect and a text. the rect is the color of the square, while the text is the piece. If you change the transform of the text outside the range of the g element it disappears. Either way it feels a wrong model for moving pieces.

Supposing you are drawing your board and then, independently, draw your pieces, you might use the example in the link above to move the pieces where you want. Take care with the knight, you should move it with two transitions, though, and probably you should think a bit about the capturing animation.

That's all I got.