# How to add an image to a svg element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am building a svg element in pure Javascript, but I don't manage to add images to it :

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var svgElement = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
svgElement.setAttributeNS(null, "width", 100);
svgElement.setAttributeNS(null, "height", 100);

var shape = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 25);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  20);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");

var pngImage = document.createElementNS(svgns, "image");
pgnImage.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 0);
pgnImage.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 0);
pgnImage.setAttributeNS(null, "width", 100);
pgnImage.setAttributeNS(null, "height", 100);
pngImage.setAttributeNS(null, "http://www.freedos.org/images/logos/fdfish-glossy-plain.svg")


svgElement.appendChild(shape);
svgElement.appendChild(pgnImage);

document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
```

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loloof64/50mu0gmg/4/)

Comment: What are you trying to do? SVG are Scalable Vector Graphics... they are images, however they use coordinates instead of set pixels... Are you trying to draw your own points? Good luck!

Comment: Create an image element inside of the svg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images#6250418

Comment: Updtated the JSFiddle to use an svg instead of a png image.

Comment: @user104317 I want to do this in Javascript because the use case is in a angular directive creation.

Comment: Note that there is a typo in pgnImage instead of pngImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this to set the href attribute, although why you're calling the variable pngImage when it sets a svg image is beyond me.

```
pngImage.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "http://www.freedos.org/images/logos/fdfish-glossy-plain.svg")
```

You're also confused about whether the variable is pngImage or pgnImage, a browser debugger will inform you of that problem.

[Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/50mu0gmg/7/)

Comment: Thank you. I need this feature because I want to import external svg files. The use case is simply : building a chess grid, and import pieces pictures.

Comment: How about this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806132/how-to-draw-a-chess-board-in-d3

Comment: Thank you but i really want to do this in plain Javascript. And I nearly achieved.

Comment: I have googled for hours to find this answer thanks mate!